# How to delete orphan data in elasticsearch after shrink?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch said the index data is 65Gb. But data folder size on disk is 95 Gb. So, how to find & delete those 30Gb?

On my windows server, I had elasticsearch version 6.1 with almost 70Gb of data. After upgrade to 6.7, I set up a lifecycle policy to shrink old indices. I suppose that the shrinking process left some data (old indices?) on disk.
If it relates to issue, my elastic health looks normal:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 311,
  "active_shards" : 311,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

I can see old indices in monitoring with status Deleted/Closed. For example:

```
log-2018.08.01
Health: Deleted / Closed Deleted / Closed
25.2 MB

log-2018.08.02
Health: Deleted / Closed Deleted / Closed
65.2 MB

log-2018.08.03
Health: Deleted / Closed Deleted / Closed
99.9 MB
```

But elasticsearch indicates them as an alias:

```
DELETE /log-2018.08.01

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "The provided expression [log-2018.08.01] matches an alias, specify the corresponding concrete indices instead."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "The provided expression [log-2018.08.01] matches an alias, specify the corresponding concrete indices instead."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**UPD**
I suppose, there is a bug, which led to orphaned files. I run the query:

```
GET /log-2018.08.01/_settings/*uuid
```

And get the result:

```
{
  "shrink-log-2018.08.01" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "resize" : {
          "source" : {
            "uuid" : "CDwuD72lSs-1CMsoIFFQiw"
          }
        },
        "shrink" : {
          "source" : {
            "uuid" : "CDwuD72lSs-1CMsoIFFQiw"
          }
        },
        "uuid" : "mKZ4VWwnTVWkZGw77pMbwg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both folders (source "CDwuD72lSs-1CMsoIFFQiw" and shrink "mKZ4VWwnTVWkZGw77pMbwg") exist on disk. But elastic said that log-2018.08.01 is an alias. 
And source index looks broken/cutted (no "state" for example)

```
├───0
│   └───index
│           _3p.dim
│           _3p.fdt
│           _3p.nvd
│           _3p_Lucene50_0.doc
│           _3p_Lucene50_0.pos
│           _3p_Lucene50_0.tim
│           _3p_Lucene70_0.dvd
```

Comment: It's probably because the chosen timespan includes old indices. If they have been deleted, your disk space should be fine.

Comment: I've been edited the question. So, it's not indices, but aliases, and I can not delete them.

Comment: what kind of indexes do you have behind that alias?

Comment: It's an alias for shrinking index. log-2018.08.01 points to shrink-log-2018.08.01